# remove all options from select tag

Tags: javascript

Here i have a select element and couple of option elements.I want to delete all option elements by running a foreach loop on them.But only first two elements are getting removed.What is wrong with this code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id='item'></p>
<form>
remove all from fruit list:
<br>
<select id="mySelect" size="4" class='myclass' onChange='myFunction(this.className);'>
  <option id='for_apple'>Apple</option>
  <option>Pear</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
</select>



<script>
 let select_item = document.getElementById('mySelect');
 let options=select_item.getElementsByTagName('option');
 console.log('length is : '+options.length);
 Array.prototype.forEach.call(options,(elem,index,arr) => {

     console.log(options.length);
     select_item.removeChild(elem);
 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My guess is that `options` updates live: After removing 2 elements, its length becomes 4-2 == 2, so the loop just stops there.

Comment: Just use `select_item.innerHTML = "";` Or use this: `while (options.length) select_item.removeChild(options[0]);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nodelists are "live", so when you iterate over them, the length changes and the loop stops.

The solution is to iterate backwards

```
let select_item = document.getElementById('mySelect');
let options = select_item.getElementsByTagName('option');

for (var i=options.length; i--;) {
    select_item.removeChild(options[i]);
}
```

Comment: if they are live then length property should also update ,shouldn't it ?and with no condition to check it will create an infinite loop ?

Comment: When you start a `forEach` loop it checks the length, and assumes you're going to iterate over 4 elements. It then removes the first element at `options[0]` and updates the nodelist. Now it has three elements, the first one again at `[0]`. It gets the second element at `[1]` and updates the nodeList again, and now you have two elements, one at `[0]` and one at `[1]`. The forEach loop now tries to get the third element, the one at `[2]`, but there is no element in that location as the nodeList updated itself.

Comment: thanks..i have another question regarding the for loop,it doesn't have any constraint..how does it know when to stop?

Comment: It stops when it's falsy, i.e. when it reaches `0`

Answer (score 3):

Bit of an old post, but setting the length to 0 is a quicker option:

```
document.getElementById('mySelect').options.length = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

`$("#mySelect option").remove();`

This will remove all options under your `#mySelect` tag. All of the arrays and loops are not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use non live querySelectorAll instead

```
let options = document.querySelectorAll('#mySelect option');
```

Comment: @AL-zami [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a non live nodelist..

Comment: ok thanks :)...i just checked https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to [convert the NodeList into an array](https://davidwalsh.name/nodelist-array) before calling `forEach` on it:

```
[].slice.call(options).forEach((elem,index,arr) => {
    console.log(options.length);
    select_item.removeChild(elem);
});
```

Better yet, since you are already using ES2015 syntax just use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to do it:

```
[...options].forEach((elem,index,arr) => {
    console.log(options.length);
    select_item.removeChild(elem);
});
```

Or [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```
Array.from(options).forEach((elem,index,arr) => {
    console.log(options.length);
    select_item.removeChild(elem);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

better used pure java script.

```
[...document.getElementById('elementId')].map(x=>x.remove())
```